# TypeScript error Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type Appstate despite having all necessary types included

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a main App component where I have defined the types for all the elements used.

I'm making an API call and getting back a response and then attempting to update part of the state based on that response and I'm getting the following error:

```
Argument of type 'User & { entries: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AppState | ((prevState: Readonly<AppState>, props: Readonly<{}>) => AppState | Pick<AppState, "input" | "imageUrl" | "box" | "route" | "isSignedIn" | "user"> | null) | Pick<...> | null'.
  Type 'User & { entries: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<AppState, "input" | "imageUrl" | "box" | "route" | "isSignedIn" | "user">': input, imageUrl, box, route, and 2 more.ts(2345)
```

I'm not entirely sure how to go about fixing this because I have all of the types defined and included in the same file as shown below:

```
type User = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  entries: number;
  joined: string;
};

type AppState = {
  input: string;
  imageUrl: string;
  box: Box;
  route: string;
  isSignedIn: boolean;
  user: User;
};

class App extends Component<{}, AppState> {
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: "",
      imageUrl: "",
      box: {
        leftCol: undefined,
        topRow: undefined,
        rightCol: undefined,
        bottomRow: undefined,
      },
      route: "signin",
      isSignedIn: false,
      user: {
        id: "",
        name: "",
        email: "",
        entries: 0,
        joined: "",
      },
    };
  }

onPictureSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({ imageUrl: this.state.input });

    try {
      clarifaiApp.models
        .predict(
          Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL,
          // URL
          this.state.input
        )
        .then((response: any) => {
          if (response) {
            fetch("http://localhost:3000/image", {
              method: "put",
              headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
              body: JSON.stringify({
                id: this.state.user.id,
              }),
            })
              .then((response) => response.json())
              .then((count: number) => {
                // This line is where I'm getting the error starting at Object.assign
                this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.user, { entries: count }))
              });
          }
          this.displayBoundingBox(this.calculateFacePosition(response));
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("There was an error: ", err);
    }
  };


render() {
    const { isSignedIn, box, imageUrl, route } = this.state;

    return (
      <Container>
         ...
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I'm still somewhat new to TypeScript so this is one of those times where I'm completely stumped on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.setState({user: Object.assign(this.state.user, { entries: count })})
```

instead of

```
this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.user, { entries: count }))
```

Otherwise, you re-write the entire state object with `Object.assign(this.state.user, { entries: count })`

Typescript errors are a pain but just remember that the last line always makes the most sense.

```
Type 'User & { entries: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<AppState, "input" | "imageUrl" | "box" | "route" | "isSignedIn" | "user">': input, imageUrl, box, route, and 2 more.ts(2345)
```

Is basically saying "your state object is missing input, imageUrl, etc."

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much and thanks for the tip on how to decipher TS errors, they've been killing me lately haha